Calculation of DNL, INL of a Flash ADC using cadence virtuoso
I have designed a 3bit flash ADC, with a supply voltage of 1.2 V. ADC ADC wave form. here r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6 are the divided reference voltages. b0,b1,b2 are the outputs(3 bit output).
Input is a sine wave with 1.2 V amplitude and frequency of 100 kHz. and a reference voltage of 0.5 V.
i have designed a flash ADC and now  i have to calculates it's DNL,INL, gain error etc. how to calculate these?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
